# c++ std::log function doesn't scale

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm running a piece of code to test if the log() function in  scales. I ran it on a 4-core machine and the result shows that it does no scale. My code is as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<omp.h>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;

typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;

int main(){
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

                double tmp=1.0;
                for(double j=0.0;j<10000000;j++){
                        tmp=log(j);
                }

                auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                #pragma omp critical
                {
                        cout<<"tmp="<<tmp<<endl;
                        cout<<"Thread "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<" calculated tmp, time used: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(end - start).count() << "ms" << endl;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

If I use 4 threads, the result is:

```
Thread 1 calculated tmp, time used: 21ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 21ms
Thread 2 calculated tmp, time used: 21ms
Thread 3 calculated tmp, time used: 21ms
```

If only using 1 thread, the result is:

```
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 20ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 16ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 16ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 15ms
```

So when running in parallel, each thread takes longer than running in sequential. Does anybody know why it doesn't scale? How does the std::log actually work (may there's something that the threads have to share)? Is there any way to have a log() function that scales? Thanks!

EDIT1:
I increased the number of iterations to 10e10 times, but the result shows that the parallel version is even slower, so maybe it's not the thread creation time which is dominant here.
4 threads:

```
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 17890ms
Thread 2 calculated tmp, time used: 17890ms
Thread 1 calculated tmp, time used: 17892ms
Thread 3 calculated tmp, time used: 17892ms
```

1 thread:

```
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 15664ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 15659ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 15660ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 15647ms
```

EDIT2: I let the tmp variable to be printed out in the end, so that the log() can't be optimized out. But the result is still like before. Any other ideas?

EDIT3: So the speed-up of the total execution time is 3.5, and it does not become higher anymore even if the number of iterations increases. I'm not sure whether it's a reasonable speed-up, because I was expecting a speed-up like 3.7 or 3.8 on for a simple program like this.

Comment: Thread creation is expensive.  You need to do more work in the thread vs it's creation time.

Comment: Your log calculation probably gets optimized out. It doesn't do anything observable.

Comment: What happens if you make loop to iterate over integers, not doubles?

Comment: @RichardCritten The speed-up doesn't change if I change the iterator to integers. The absolute time becomes longer both of the parallel version and the sequential version, which I guess is for the type conversion.

Comment: I don't think that thread creation can take so much time , because for this example program create 4 threads and difference between 10e10 and 10e7 can't be so big

Comment: Just because you print out the tmp variable does not mean it won't be optimized out afaik.

Comment: What is the total execution time in each case? Even if each thread takes longer, they can still work faster together.

Comment: The compiler may realize that the loop can be removed, and replaced with just `tmp = log(9999999);`

Comment: I think Revolver_Ocelot is on the right track. You are measuring the wrong time. Total execution time is what matters, not what each thread takes to execute.

Comment: As you're on a 4 core machine 4 threads may not be optimal (as there are other things to take care of), you could try with 3 threads to see how the number of threads vs the number of core impact the results.

Comment: Is this a 4 core machine, or a 2 core machine with hyperthreading?  Does it have single-core boost, where when running single core it overclocks that core?  In short, what exactly is your hardware?   Finally, multithreaded code rarely scales perfectly.  The case where it does is the surprising one.

Comment: Interesting detail: If I use 4 threads on a machine with 4 real cores each thread is about 5 percent slower but if I use 8 threads (on 8 hyperthreading cores) each thread is only about 48% slower than a single running thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**

You are completely right.  But to fully measure the multicore performance improvement, you shouldn't rely solely on timing individual threads : you should time as well measure the overall execution.

Multicore architectures seem to achieve higher throughput at the expense of a slight decrease of each core when several of them are active.  Here [another benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35525942/3723423) (using `std::thread` instead of OMP) with similar observations.

So each individual log calculation doesn't scale, but the oveall system does very well.

**Additional details**

If you'd run some overall end-to-end measurements:

```
int main()
{
    auto common_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ... 
    auto common_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Overall calculated time : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(common_end - common_start).count() << "ms" << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

you'd certainly observe a better overall performance in parallel.

Here my own timings with 4 threads:

```
Thread 2 calculated tmp, time used: 269ms
Thread 3 calculated tmp, time used: 274ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 281ms
Thread 1 calculated tmp, time used: 289ms
Overall calculated time : 296ms
```

and with one:

```
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 218ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 218ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 229ms
Thread 0 calculated tmp, time used: 224ms
Overall calculated time : 903ms
```

As you already observed, with one thread the calculations are performed 22% faster.  But overall, it takes 3 times the time needed in multithreading to do the same number of calculations.

So it's all about throughput: run at only 44 K-iterations/ms monothread compared to 135 K-iterations/ms with multithreading.