# C++ multithreading performance slower than single threaded code

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm learning to use thread in c++ 
I created a very long vector with integers and set another integer x.  And I want to calculate the difference between that integer and the integers in the vector. 

However, in my implementation, the function using two threads is slower than a single thread function.  I wonder why is the reason, and how can I implement threading correctly so it does run faster. 

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


vector<int> vector_generator(int size) {
    vector<int> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp.push_back(i);
    }
    return temp;
}

vector<int> dist_calculation(int center, vector<int> &input, int start, int end) {
    vector<int> temp;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        temp.push_back(abs(center - input[i]));
    }
    return temp;
}


void multi_dist_calculation(int center, vector<int> &input) {
    int mid = input.size() / 2;

    vector<int> temp1(input.begin(), input.begin() + mid);
    vector<int> temp2(input.begin()+mid, input.end());

    auto future1 = async(dist_calculation, center, temp1, 0, mid);
    auto future2 = async(dist_calculation, center, temp2, 0, mid);

    vector<int> result1 = future1.get();
    vector<int> result2 = future2.get();

    return;
}


int main() {

    vector<int> v1 = vector_generator(1000000000);
    vector<int> result;
    multi_dist_calculation(0, v1);
    //dist_calculation(50, v1, 0, v1.size());

    return 0;
}
```

**Update #1**

Added suggestions of *std::launch::async* & *reserve()*, and it does make the code faster.  But the 2-threaded function is still slower than single threaded one.  Can I say in this kind of calculation, single-threaded is faster?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


vector<int> vector_generator(int size) {
    vector<int> temp;
    temp.reserve(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp.push_back(i);
    }
    return temp;
}

vector<int> dist_calculation(int center, vector<int> &input, int start, int end) {
    vector<int> temp;
    temp.reserve(end - start);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        temp.push_back(abs(center - input[i]));
    }
    return temp;
}


void multi_dist_calculation(int center, vector<int> &input) {
    int mid = input.size() / 2;

    auto future1 = async(std::launch::async, dist_calculation, center, input,   0, mid);
    auto future2 = async(std::launch::async, dist_calculation, center, input, mid, input.size());

    vector<int> result1 = future1.get();
    vector<int> result2 = future2.get();

    return;
}


int main() {

    vector<int> v1 = vector_generator(1000000000);
    vector<int> result;
    int center = 0;
    multi_dist_calculation(center, v1);
    //dist_calculation(center, v1, 0, v1.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't set launch policy in your `async` calls. Isn't that UB? Try using `async(std::launch::async, dist_calculation, center, temp1, 0, mid);`.

Comment: How did you measure? How many cores does your hardware provide?

Comment: Could be of interest about why multithread can be slower than single thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35525942/3723423

Comment: Currently you have asynchronous calculations that may or may not be multithreaded. Also this code suffers from huge overhead caused by reallocations.

Comment: Can you give numbers? If the execution of the threads is very short this may give poor results.

Comment: I set up breakpoints in visual studio, and it gives me the duration between breakpoints in diagnostic tools.  I've 6-core/12-threads.  The 2-threaded function used about 9.33 sec, and single-threaded used about 7.65 secs

Comment: So you are running in debug mode with optimisations turned off then ?

Comment: @Ian Nope, but fyi, in both debug and release mode, single threaded code run faster

Comment: @freakish -- if no launch policy is specified in a call to `async` it applies a launch policy of `launch::async | launch::deferred`. [futures.async]/3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not pass any `std::launch policy` to [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), so it leaves the implementation a lot of freedom.

> Behaves as if (2) is called with policy being std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred. In other words, f may be executed in another thread or it **may be run synchronously** when the resulting std::future is queried for a value.

But also be aware that more generally, using more threads, especially on small tasks may not be faster.

- Where `dist_calculation` or any task you want to thread is a small amount of work, be aware of the overheads. Creating a new thread has a relatively high cost, and there is also overhead for whatever internal pool `std::async` uses, promises, and futures.
- Additionally, the way written, it is likely you create more vectors, with more dynamic memory, and you will need to merge the results which will also have some cost.
- In more complex cases, if synchronization, e.g. with `std::mutex` is involved, that may cost more performance than additional threads gain.
- In some cases, the bottleneck will not be the CPU. For example it may be disk/storage speed (including for page/swap file), network speed (including remote servers), or even memory bandwidth (excepting NUMA aware optimizations, they are a lot more complex than just using `std::async`). Multithreading in these will just add overheads, but no benefit.

You should make use of other basic optimisations where possible first, such as `reserve` the size of the vectors to avoid unneeded allocations and copies, maybe `resize` and use the `vector[index] = a` instead of `push_back`, etc.

For something as simple as `abs(centre - input[i])` you might get a lot more improvement from SIMD (Single instruction multiple data) optimisations. e.g. make sure you are compiling with any optimizations such as `SSE2` enabled, and if the compiler doesn't optimise the loop appropriately (I think the `push_back` may interfere, test!), alter it slightly so it does, or maybe even use the vector instructions explicitly (for x86 check out `_mm_add_epi32` etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will def. look into it.  BTW, I was using std::thread instead of std::async, and it produced the same result which single-threaded is faster. Was it due to the same reason?

Comment: @User800222, `async` is an abstraction built on top of `std::thread`. I am not surprised the two implementations behave similarly.

Comment: I used std::thread & std::ref() to get the calculated result, but I saw someone of stackoverflow saying thats a bad way to do it.  Then I looked it up further and found out people recommend to use std::async() if you want threads to return values.

Comment: @User800222 That's not a bad way to do it. Everything in the language is there for you to utilize. Your execution time is probably dominated by all the vector copying, slicing and resizing (note that heap allocators often utilize locks to serialize execution, **you have an implicit lock in your code** on `push_back`, because you didn't `reserve`). Here's an idea: for the given `input` allocate `result` vector with the same size in `multi_dist_calculation`. Then pass both (as reference) to separate threads together with `start, end` boundaries and update the `result`.

Comment: I've added the suggestions, and it does overall make the code faster, but single-threaded function is still faster.  Can I say it for sure that in this case single-threaded is better in this kind of calculation? btw, adding std::launch::async doesnt seem to do much

Comment: Did you change your `std::async` call?

Comment: @FireLancer yes, I did.  Please see the updated code in the update#1 section.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly, then your singlethreaded version simply calls `dist_calculation` on the given vector, which will run through the vector once and produce a new vector which it returns. Your multithreaded version, on the other hand, first copies each half of the input data to two separate vectors. After that, it launches the `dist_calculation` for each half, potentially in two threads. [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) may not even run using a separate thread because you didn't specify a launch policy. If it happens to run using a separate thread, the vectors you pass will be copied once more due to the way the [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) constructor works. You'd have to use, e.g., an [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to properly pass a reference. Think about what's going on there. Copying the data to these two vectors means that you're already running through the entire data once before you even get to the point where you'd be launching some threads to perform the actual computation, *if* threads are even going to be used to begin with. And if they are, you're copying the data a second time. Both times, the copy happens in a single thread. So just to get to the point where your actual multithreaded computation starts—if it does actually happen using multiple threads—your "multithreaded" version has basically had to do three times the work that your singlethreaded version will do in total. And it had to do all of that in a single thread…

Your `dist_calculation` does not modify the original data. Furthermore, the individual threads are going to access completely separate parts of the data. Thus, there is no need to ever copy the data at all. Simply give each thread a pointer/iterator to the part of the original data it should process. Also, you know beforehand how many elements are going to be produced. So rather than continuously growing two separate output vectors, you could just preallocate a vector to receive the output and give each thread yet another pointer to the subrange of the output vector it should write to.

And finally, starting with C++17, you could just use the parallel versions of [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with `std::execution::par_unseq` and get yourself an automagically parallelized (potentially even vectorized) solution. [For example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cnumeric%3E%0A%23include+%3Cexecution%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+ExecutionPolicy,+typename+ForwardIterator,+typename+OutputIterator%3E%0Avoid+multi_dist_calculation(OutputIterator+dest,+ForwardIterator+begin,+ForwardIterator+end,+int+center,+ExecutionPolicy%26%26+execution_policy)%0A%7B%0A%09std::transform(std::forward%3CExecutionPolicy%3E(execution_policy),+begin,+end,+dest,+%5Bcenter%5D(int+x)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+std::abs(center+-+x)%3B%0A++++%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+int+data_size+%3D+1000000000%3B%0A%09auto+data+%3D+std::unique_ptr%3Cint%5B%5D%3E+%7B+new+int%5Bdata_size%5D+%7D%3B%0A%09std::iota(%26data%5B0%5D,+%26data%5B0%5D+%2B+data_size,+0)%3B%0A%0A%09auto+result+%3D+std::unique_ptr%3Cint%5B%5D%3E+%7B+new+int%5Bdata_size%5D+%7D%3B%0A%09multi_dist_calculation(%26result%5B0%5D,+%26data%5B0%5D,+%26data%5B0%5D+%2B+data_size,+0,+std::execution::par_unseq)%3B%0A++++//+multi_dist_calculation(%26result%5B0%5D,+%26data%5B0%5D,+%26data%5B0%5D+%2B+data_size,+0,+std::execution::seq)%3B%0A%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.83017635532332,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_20_x64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'/std:c%2B%2B17+-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x64+msvc+v19.20+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.16982364467668,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
template <typename ExecutionPolicy, typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void multi_dist_calculation(OutputIterator dest, ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end, int center, ExecutionPolicy&& execution_policy)
{
    std::transform(std::forward<ExecutionPolicy>(execution_policy), begin, end, dest, [center](int x)
    {
        return std::abs(center - x);
    });
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int data_size = 1000000000;
    auto data = std::unique_ptr<int[]> { new int[data_size] };
    std::iota(&data[0], &data[0] + data_size, 0);

    auto result = std::unique_ptr<int[]> { new int[data_size] };
    multi_dist_calculation(&result[0], &data[0], &data[0] + data_size, 0, std::execution::par_unseq);  // multithreaded
    // multi_dist_calculation(&result[0], &data[0], &data[0] + data_size, 0, std::execution::seq);  // singlethreaded

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know its been a while, after realizing how transform works, your code has been really informative.  They are just so many useful std functions that not many people know, and thank you for bringing this up.  One question tho, when doing multi-threading with transform, is there a way to specify how many threads for function to use?

Comment: @User800222 I'm afraid there's currently no standard way to influence how many threads will be used. One can hope that the work currently going on with executors may also result in some more control on how the parallel standard algorithms are scheduled, but that remains to be seen…